# kohana3.3.0 native session lifetime expired by incorrect calculation

Tags: php, session-timeout, kohana-3.3

bootstrap.php:

```
Session::$default="native";
```

my session configure file:

```
return array(
    'native' => array(
        'name' => 'session',
        'lifetime' => 10, // 10 secs
    ),
);
```

I found the calculation of expired time is `time() - session_created_time > lifetime`, not `time() - last_active_time > lifetime`. is anyone who could told me how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added one statement to sync up session with client cookie, everything is ok. 
`setcookie($this->_name, session_id(), time()+$this->_lifetime, Cookie::$path, Cookie::$domain, Cookie::$secure, Cookie::$httponly);` 
in system\classes\Kohana\Session\Native.php#protected function _read($id = NULL)

Answer (score 0):

According to what I see in the Kohana's code, session['native']['lifetime'] is not working. I searched in the code for

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', xxx)
```

and didnt find it. I had to put that line on my bootstrap.php

Can you tell me whether session['native']['lifetime'] is working or not?